# add left and right portions of the array symmetrically - python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
a = np.array([[[ 1, 11],
               [ 3, 13],
               [ 5, 15],
               [ 7, 17],
               [ 9, 19]],

              [[ 2, 12],
               [ 4, 14],
               [ 6, 16],
               [ 8, 18],
               [10, 20]]])
```

I'm trying to add the left portion to the right portion of the array in a symmetrical way along the second dimension (so `1+9`, `11+19`, `3+7`, `13+17` for the first sub array above).

I tried this

```
>>> middle = int(np.ceil(a.shape[1]/2))
>>> a[:,:middle-1,:] + a[:,middle:,:]
array([[[ 8, 28],
        [12, 32]],

       [[10, 30],
        [14, 34]]], dtype=uint8)
```

which adds the left to the right but not symmetrically. This is what I'm hoping to get

```
array([[[10, 30],
        [10, 30]],

       [[12, 32],
        [12, 32]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like any concept of "left" or "right" that I can make sense of.

Comment: @user2357112 OP has `numpy` on their side. Try `fliplr(a)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small modification to your code will work:

```
middle = int(np.ceil(a.shape[1]/2))
print(a[:,:middle-1,:] + a[:,:middle-1:-1,:])
```

The second addend is sliced differently here to reverse it. (Original was `a[:,middle:,:]`)

Result:

```
[[[10 30]
  [10 30]]

 [[12 32]
  [12 32]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you may invert the array, add and cut to the `a.shape[1]//2` middle

```
(a + a[:,::-1,:])[:, :a.shape[1]//2, :]
```

---

```
array([[[10, 30],
        [10, 30]],

       [[12, 32],
        [12, 32]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use backward slicing "`[b:a:-1]`"

```
i,j,k = a.shape
a[:,:j//2] + a[:,:(j-1)//2:-1]
# array([[[10, 30],
#         [10, 30]],
#
#        [[12, 32],
#         [12, 32]]])
```

Or to avoid the slightly error prone computation of the backward limits you can use `np.fliplr`

```
half = np.s_[:,:a.shape[1]//2]
a[half] + np.fliplr(a)[half]
# array([[[10, 30],
#         [10, 30]],
#
#        [[12, 32],
#         [12, 32]]])
```